# Prevent XmlSerializer from formatting output

Tags: c#, xml, formatting, xml-serialization

When using the default settings with the XmlSerializer it will output the XML as a formated value.

IE: something along these lines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfStock xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Stock>
    <ProductCode>12345</ProductCode>
    <ProductPrice>10.32</ProductPrice>
  </Stock>
  <Stock>
    <ProductCode>45632</ProductCode>
    <ProductPrice>5.43</ProductPrice>
  </Stock>
</ArrayOfStock>
```

How does one prevent any type of formatting on the output? So what I am looking to achieve is this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ArrayOfStock xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><Stock><ProductCode>123456</ProductCode><ProductPrice>10.57</ProductPrice></Stock><Stock><ProductCode>789123</ProductCode><ProductPrice>133.22</ProductPrice></Stock></ArrayOfStock>
```

EDIT: The full code of my method is

```
public static String Serialize(Stock stock)
{
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Stock));

     using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
     {
         serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, stock);
         return stringWriter.ToString();
     }            
}
```

Comment: Why does the formatting  matter? Is it causing a problem?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Not very intuitive, but the `Indent` property on the `XmlWriterSettings` controls the whole formatting:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));

using (var writer = new StreamWriter("file.path"))
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = false }))
{
    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, myObject);
}
```

There are a few more options on [`XmlWriterSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx) that you might want to explore.

Comment: I think Indent is by default false because I had same code as yours (without Settings) and wanted it formatted so I had to change Indent to true.

Comment: Yes, Indent is false by default on `XmlWritterSettings` so I guess it can be omitted from the code above. But if you use the `XmlSerializer` without explicitly giving it an `XmlWriter`, it will use its own and enable formatting/indenting by default.

Comment: The comment from @XavierPoinas about default value is very important.

Answer (score 0):

..

```
XmlSerializer xmlser = new XmlSerializer(...);

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings {Indent = false};

using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
{
```

...

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to parse the resulting XML and remove and newlines and tabs...
using 'Indent = false', will still put elements on newlines no?

Comment: Ok, so seems the Indent option controls more than just indenting... badly named perhaps?