# C# Error 'System.Text.Encoding.GetString(byte[])' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am trying to convert Object to xml using silverlight 5 and c# and i have following error:

```
Error   1   'System.Text.Encoding.GetString(byte[])' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

corresponding to line:

```
 return utf8.GetString(mem.ToArray());
```

in my Xml.cs class

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace SliderLastTry
{
    public static class Xml
    {
        public static string ToXml(this object objectToSerialize)
        {
            var mem = new MemoryStream();
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
            ser.Serialize(mem, objectToSerialize);
            var utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            return utf8.GetString(mem.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Paramter.cs is:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SliderLastTry
{
    public  class Parameter 
    { 
        public  string Name {get; set; } 
    }  
}
```

Main function containing class is:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SliderLastTry
{
    public static class ControlClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Parameter pram = new Parameter();
            pram.ToXml();

        }

    }
}
```

**Could some one please help me in fixing my error ?**

Comment: I've copied your code an no error here, not on build, not on execution.

Comment: I am using silverlight5 c# is that a problem.

Comment: I'm not aware of a Silverlight context, I'm just using a console application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, your best bet here is actually to use `StringWriter`, since a .NET `string` is **not** a direct map to UTF-8 (it is actually UTF-16, if anything):

```
using(var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    ser.Serialize(writer, objectToSerialize);
    return writer.ToString();
}
```

This also has the performance advantage of avoiding an additional duplicate of all the data (`string` vs `byte[]`).

If you **must** use the `byte[]` version, you can use a different overload to specify the bounds of the array. Note also that passing in the underlying buffer avoids a *third* duplicate of the data (i.e. the underlying `byte[]` in the memory-stream, the temporary `byte[]` returned from `ToArray()`, and the data that ends up in the `string`).

```
return utf8.GetString(mem.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)mem.Length);
```

Comment: thanks a lot. You really xml expert. I have one mre question suppose if i print this xml in a file. Then is it possible to print it in formatted manner(rather then a continous string) ?

Comment: @user234839 that is controlled by the `XmlWriterSettings` class; to do *that* you need to have an `XmlWriter` as well; see here, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5414617/23354 - basically, you'd have a `StringWriter` that is wrapped by the `XmlWriter`, then have the `XmlSerializer` write to the `XmlWriter`; see MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 4):

I guess silverlight doesn't have the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which takes only `byte[]` for some reason.

You just need to use [another overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05cts4c3%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which takes `index` and `count` as well.

```
var bytes = mem.ToArray();
return utf8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

FWIW `GetString` internally calls another overload the same way :)