# Why xml serialization adds an extra whitespace character inside the element?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize an object to XML and the problem that I am getting is that the object gets serialized to

```
<something />
```

instead of

`<something/>`

I believe that both are valid XML syntax, but I have to get `<something/>`

Here is my code

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T ObjectToSerialize)
{
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
    {
        OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
        Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    };

    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(ObjectToSerialize.GetType());

    using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xw, ObjectToSerialize);

        }

        return textWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did setting Indent=false helped you ?  [Look at this answer for code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414617/prevent-xmlserializer-from-formatting-output)

Comment: Also why do you want to omit the space ?  If you are deserializing, it will not cause any issue as such.

Comment: It only occurs if the node is empty.  Normally you get <something>abc</something>

Comment: @ManojChoudhari Indent=false didnt help

Comment: @ManojChoudhari I have to omit it, as it is requested by 3rd party integration. I agree with you that shouldnt be an issue, but I have to fix it... not sure how.

Comment: @jdweng i agree, but the question is how to display an empty node like <something/> without hiding it completely

Comment: This is [hard-coded](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextWriter.cs,1159)

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462741/space-before-closing-slash). Maybe it'll be more clear to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not be the most efficient solution, but you could do a simple `String.Replace` before returning serialized data in `Serialize<T>()`.

Replacing

```
 return textWriter.ToString();
```

With

```
 return textWriter.ToString().Replace(" />","/>");
```

Comment: That is what i did at the end, but was looking for a more cleaner solution